# Ошибка ssh: handshake failed: ssh: first packet should be msgKexInit

Tags: golang, ssh

Надо подключиться к свитчу, поддерживающему только SSH1, при создании подключения появляется такая ошибка, гугл выдает только файл handshake.go из пакета SSH для GO, где есть только условие этой ошибки.

Comment: если там действительно только протокол ssh первой версии, то в виде библиотеки для go вы вряд ли найдёте реализацию этого протокола (а он [несовместим с ssh второй версии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH#%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)). пишите сами, или наймите того, кто сможет написать, или используйте не-go реализацию протокола.

Comment: … что-то вроде этого, как я понимаю: https://github.com/karfield/ssh2go , там используется libssh, которая, вроде бы, «умеет» и первую версию протокола.

Comment: да, libssh — умеет: [SSHv2 and SSHv1 protocol support](http://api.libssh.org/stable/)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin просто в конфиге для подключения есть параметр ClientVersion, если для ssh1 он будет SSH-2.0-Go или наоборот, то ошибка будет ssh: package too large, а если версии совпадают, то ssh2 работает, а ssh1 нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя два года сделал либу, которая кое как да работает, может кому пригодится
https://github.com/ultram4rine/go-ssh1

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, сказано: _являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт_.